# Why is it seemingly more efficient to untangle headphones by randomly juggling them rather than deliberately?

Tags: general-topology

This (semi) serious question could have an explanation in topology or just a function of human dexterity. Thoughts?

Comment: Because most people are not efficient at untangling headphones, they are so inefficient that it doesn't work and they get irritated, from which they cannot untangle their headphones, from which they get even more frustrated, and the process continues. However, with practice...

Comment: I'm thinking most headphones get "overtangled" because they're in an enclosed space. Bringing them into the open and shaking them brings them to "tangled".

Comment: I'd lean towards the first, more obvious answer too, however since "most" people naturally use this method, I wonder if there is something about randomness that applies to the physics of this particular system. Does anyone think this could be modeled?
e.g - P(E) = prob of a "correct" move that leads to untangling via random movement. You could attach a cost function that represents the amount of time required to purposely untie one step. I would think that you could model which method is more effective given the complexity of the knot, but i don't know how you'd do this using topology...